# how to make category screen in vertical and display menu item beside?

Tags: flutter, menu, categories, vertical-alignment

i try to find a solution for the flutter drawer menu. i implement the normal NavigationRail and the category looks find. now i want to draw a submenu for many items.

i found this Flutter how to add a Expandable menu item inside NavigationRail drawer? but this is not what i want. this show the subitems under the header item. i want a solution to click on the category and display list of category items. here is a example what i mean.

any example code can for me to refer ?

[Example what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebyty.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use vertical list view builder and for show scree like as you want use container in row and set fix width

for exaple set two containers in row set
once width :Mediaquery.of(context).size.width/1.8
this is righ container

left container
and othher one container width
Mediaquery.of(context).size.width/4

and now set listview as child and set direction horizontal